# tag facebook friends python sdk GraphApi in put_photo

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would to post pictures and tag with frieds.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.cfg['access_token'])
tags = [{"tag_uid": "1234567890", "x": 0, "y": 0}, {"tag_uid": "0001234567890", "x": 0, "y": 0}]
graph.put_photo(image=open(str(file), 'rb'), message='Pictures test', **{'tags': tags})
```

but i've this error

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) param tags must be an array.
```

Answer (score 0):

error solved with

```
tags = [{"tag_uid": "1234567890", "x": 0, "y": 0}]
graph.put_photo(image=open(str(file), 'rb'), message='Pictures test', **{'tags[0]': tags})
```

but tags NOT appear on the facebook wall